# how to find occurrences of a file using locate

Tags: files, locate

There are multiple installation of Java on my system, some silently installed by IDEs, and I wanted to find out where they are. So I thought to use `locate` to find them. My first try of

```
locate java
```

had several thousand hits finding `.*java.*`.

Is there a way to restrict the locate to just find files with and exact name? Not path containing Java. Not files who containing Java as part of their name.

PS: I had similar problem before so please ignore the Java part and treat this as a problem of finding files. It could just as well be a question of finding all occurrences of `gcc`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From `man locate`:

> To search for a file named exactly `NAME` (not `*NAME*`), 
> use
>                 `locate -b '\NAME'`

```
locate -b '\java'
```

- `-b` - Match only the base name against the specified patterns.

Comment: Why the backslash?

Comment: @Wildcard Also from the `man` page: "*If any PATTERN contains  no  globbing  characters, locate behaves as if the pattern were `*PATTERN*`*" So including the globbing character `\\` prevents this.

Answer (score 1):

With most `locate` implementations:

```
locate '*/java'
```

should work.

When the argument doesn't contain wildcards, the argument is taken as a string to search in the file paths.

When it does contain wildcards, the wildcard has to match the full paths. So here, any path ending in `/java`.

Answer (score -1):

`find` may be a better way to locate *java* named files.

```
find . -type f -name *java*
```

If you wanted to still use locate you could use `locate -b` or you could use

```
locate java | grep java$
```

Comment: You would drop both `*` from `*java*` in the `find` command to make it equivalent to the `locate -b` alternative. And the `grep` would need to be `grep '/java$'` to only filter out the base name `java`.